# Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting a version error when trying to upload my code. I have seen other posts but since I am workign from Cloud9 it seems those are not directing me correctly. Also when using the command "ruby -v" it shows 2.2.2

Gem file below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# for Heroku deployment - as described in Ap. A of ELLS book
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.4.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.4.4'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.3.2'
  gem 'ZenTest', '4.11.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

  #gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.7.1'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
```

Comment: I think on cloud9 you need to edit the `rails runner` to point to ruby 2.2, it's probably pointed at 1.9 right now.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.c9.io/docs/writing-a-ruby-app#rvm-support
*Currently, the default version is 1.9.3*

So on the C9 console:

```
rvm use 2.2.2
```

If that fails to find 2.2.2, I think you need to install it per project basis as mentioned towards the of that post.

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Alternately you can also have a project file called .ruby-version
How to generate:

```
echo 2.2.2 > .ruby-version
```

RVM should respect this as well as rbenv if in future you use that locally
More here:
https://rvm.io/workflow/projects